# How to get selective rows from a matrix and form a new matrix in octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Suppose I have a matrix in octave

```
A = [2 3 5;
     5 6 7; 
     8 9 10;
     1 2 5]
```

Now I want to get only those rows where the last column is say equal to 5. I was wondering if there is a built in function for this, cause right now am doing it like this.

```
collection = [];
for i = 1 : size(matrix,1),
    if(matrix(i,3) == 5),
        collection = [collection; matrix(i,:)];
    end
end
```

I would be fine if there is such a method for single column matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using logical indexing on the last column so for example

```
A(:,end) == 5
```

returns a logical matrix which is true for the rows you want and false otherwise. We can use this to select rows like so

```
ind = A(:,end) == 5;
A(ind,:);
```

you can even just do it inline:

```
A(A(:,end)==5,:)
```

Comment: This is faster than the code I have written right ? Somehow I am not able to get tick; tock; to work in octave :(

Comment: did you try `tic` and `toc`? leave off the `k`. I imagine this would be a lot faster if you had a large matrix.

Comment: You are right !! for bigger matrices my code took 0.066 seconds and yours 0 seconds. I wonder why it says 0 seconds :|

Comment: @Aditya probably just a number formatting thing. Try typing `format long g` in the command line first and then running it (that might be Matlab only though but probably translates directly into Octave)